Sinkhorn Knopp algorithm - Bregman projection in update rule
I don't understand the updating rule for $u^{l+1}$ in the Sinkhorn algorithm. The below images contain all necessary definitions of the projection operators $A_1$ and $A_2$, which project a discrete joint distribution to its marginals, i.e. row and column sums. The images are taken from this paper: https://hal.science/hal-03212175/document.
If I apply the first projection in step $l$,
$\gamma^l = \text{diag}(u^l)\gamma_0 \text{diag}(v^l)$,
the update rule $(4)$ states $u^{l+1} = \mu_1 \oslash A_1 \gamma^l = \mu_1 \oslash (u^l \odot \gamma_0 v^l),$ which denotes element-wise multiplication of the vectors. One can verify this by calculating the row sum of the $\gamma^l,$ obtained in step $l$.
But in $(5),$ the $u^l \odot \gamma_0 v^l$ is replaced by $\gamma_0 v^l$ and the scaling of the vector entries by $ u^l$ disappears. Can someone shed light on the reason for this difference?
Do I understand correctly that the Sinkhorn algorithm calculates iteratively the Bregman projection of the $l^{th}$ iterate matrix $\gamma^l$ on space $C_1$ and then of $P_{C_{1}}(\gamma^l)$ on space $C_2$? If yes, what is causing the misalignment in the formulas or am I missing something? Which formula is correct?


Similarly, in the book Computational Optimal Transport (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.00567) by Cuturi and Peyré, on page 66, Remark 4.8, I don't understand why the projections are defined this way, more specifically the formulas in yellow:

My expectation would be that (in the notation of the book)
$P^{2l +1} = \text{diag}(u^{l+1}) \gamma^l = \text{diag}(u^{l+1}) \text{diag}(u^{l}) \gamma_0 \text{diag}(v^{l}) $ and
$P^{2l +2} = P^{2l +1}(\gamma^l) \text{diag}(v^{l+1}) = \text{diag}(u^{l+1}) \text{diag}(u^{l}) \gamma_0 \text{diag}(v^{l}) \text{diag}(v^{l+1}).$ So again, where is the scaling of $u^l$ and $v^l$ disappearing?
